# Redirect old sitemaps to new sitemap.xml

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I accidently had three allowed sitemap urls:

```
domain.com/sitemap.php
domain.com/sitemap
domain.com/sitemap.xml
```

How can I redirect them all to `domain.com/sitemap.xml`, the sitemap file is `sitemap.php`?

I've been trying a few different ones but they seem to result in constant loops between the `.xml` and `.php` extensions and it breaks ...

```
#Sitemap
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml sitemap.php [L, R=301]
RewriteRule ^sitemap$ http://domain.com/sitemap.xml [R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok try this code:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(sitemap)(/|\.php)?\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1.xml [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(sitemap)\.xml$ /$1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Updated question, my sitemap file is `sitemap.php`, this gives a 404?

Comment: So you want to keep external sitemap URL as `domain.com/sitemap.xml` but want to serve it from `domain.com/sitemap.php` ?

Comment: Seems to work well thanks, what does the first line match against?

Comment: First line actually make an external redirect from `/sitemap` OR `/sitemap.php` to `/sitemap.xml` but 2nd rule will do silent rewrite from `/sitemap.xml` to `/sitemap.php`